# Dynamic Controls not found on Client Side after every postback request

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, dynamic-controls

We have a requirement where we have to create controls dynamically. But once created, do not wish to recreate them on every postback.
The issue found on the web application is that on any postback request, dynamically created controls are not found on client side. Thereby, having to recreate each control on every postback. This has slowed down the application.
Is there any other way we can do this?
We are using DevExpress 15.1.6 editor suite.
Using c# as code behind language and JavaScript and JQuery as scripting languages.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have to recreate then each and postback. You need to consider each trip to the server as a fresh request, and it is.

When you first GET the page, you create the page. When you then POST (postback) to the page, it will recreate itself again and therefore you need to create the controls at that point as well.

Annoying, but no way around it that I am aware of.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, you have to recreate them in Page_Load (or earlier in the lifecycle), assigning the same id as before. From that, viewstate will reassign a value to the controls if one exists.